# C++11 Regex IfThenElse - Single, closed brackets matched OR no brackets matched

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

How can I define a c++11/ECMAScript compatible regex statement that matches strings either:

1. Containing a single, closed, pair of round brackets containing an alphanumeric string of length greater than 0 - for example the regex statement `"\(\w+\)"`, which correctly matches `"(abc_123)"` and ignores the incorrect `"(abc_123"`, `"abc_123)"` and `"abc_123"`. However, the above expression does not ignore input strings containing multiple balanced/unbalanced bracketing - I would like to exclude `"((abc_123)"`, `"(abc_123))"`, and `"((abc_123))"` from my matched results.
2. Or a single, alphanumeric word, without any unbalanced brackets - for example something like the regex statement `"\w+"` correctly matches `"abc_123"`, but unfortunately incorrectly matches with `"(abc_123"`, `"abc_123)"`, `"((abc_123)"`, `"(abc_123))"`, and `"((abc_123))"`...

For clarity, the required matchings for each the test cases above are:

- `"abc_123"` = Match,
- `"(abc_123)"` = Match,
- `"(abc_123"` = Not matched,
- `"abc_123)"` = Not matched,
- `"((abc_123)"` = Not matched,
- `"(abc_123))"` = Not matched,
- `"((abc_123))"` = Not matched.

I've been playing around with implementing the IfThenElse format suggested by http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html, but haven't gotten very far... Is there some way to limit the number of occurrences of a particular group [e.g. `"(\(){0,1}"` matches zero or one left hand round bracket], AND pass the number of repetitions of a previous group to a later group [say `"num\1"` equals the number of times the `"("` bracket appears in `"(\(){0,1}"`, then I could pass this to the corresponding closing bracket group, `"(\)){num\1}"` say...]

Comment: Are you sure this can be represented by a regular language?

Comment: Would you be willing to accept a solution using Boost.Regex instead of C++11 regex? I think it can be done if you use negative lookbehind assertions, but these are not supported by C++11 regex

Comment: It only takes about four lines of code to check this match directly. Why complicate it with a regular expression?

Comment: Balanced delimiters are a classic example of a non-regular language, so technically this isn't possible to match with a regular expression. And even though many regex libraries permit non-regular expressions, this won't carry you very far (at least not comfortably). Regex is great for lexing the input, but the actual parsing is best left to another tool. In this case, just write the parsing of the brackets "by hand", leaving a regex for matching the inner word.

Answer (score 0):

Not what do you want, I suppose, and non really elegant but...

With "or" (`|`) you should obtain a better-than-nothing solution based on `"\\(\\w+\\)|\\w+"`.

A full example follows

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>

bool isMatch (std::string const & str)
 {
   static std::regex const
      rgx { "\\(\\w+\\)|\\w+" };

   std::smatch srgx;

   return std::regex_match(str, srgx, rgx);
 }

int main() 
 {
   std::cout << isMatch("abc_123")     << std::endl; // print 1
   std::cout << isMatch("(abc_123)")   << std::endl; // print 1
   std::cout << isMatch("(abc_123")    << std::endl; // print 0
   std::cout << isMatch("abc_123)")    << std::endl; // print 0
   std::cout << isMatch("((abc_123)")  << std::endl; // print 0
   std::cout << isMatch("(abc_123))")  << std::endl; // print 0
   std::cout << isMatch("((abc_123))") << std::endl; // print 0
 }
```

Comment: I had the impression the OP wanted to find matching substrings contained in the input (eg. regex_search instead of regex_match). Otherwise it's trivial to solve as you have done.

Comment: @harmic - isn't clear to me what the OP want; your impression can be right but... in this case why "(abc_123" should fail? Hoping that OP could clarify. And, yes: my solution is really trivial. But its real problem is that is repeat the part between parentheses: if we need to accept other type of encloding parentheses (`[]` or `{}`) we need repeat the `\\w+` part.